# Solution of PDE's by Laplace transform.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

W = $-\frac{1}{s^2}e^{\frac{-sx^2}{2}}+\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s^2}$

I know that inverse Laplace for $\frac{1}{s^2}$ = t

and

$\frac{1}{s}$ = 1

Just need some help with: $-\frac{1}{s^2}e^{\frac{-sx^2}{2}}$

The text book gives solution as:$-\frac{1}{s^2}e^{\frac{-sx^2}{2}}$ = -(t - $\frac{1}{2}x^2$)$\;\;$u(t - $\frac{1}{2}x^2$)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you have function $f(t-c)U(t-c)$ where $U$ is a step function and $c$ is a constant. Then the Laplace transform of $f(t-c)U(t-c)$ is $e^{-cs} \cal L\{f(t-c)\}$, so the inverse Laplace transform of $e^{-cs} \cal L\{f(t-c)\}$ is $f(t-c)U(t-c)$. In your case, the constant $c$ is $c=\frac{1}{2}x^2$ and $f(t)=-t$.

Comment: Also recall that $U(t-c)=1$ if $t\geq c$ and zero if $0\leq t<c$.